# Unable to match arbitrary routes in clojurescript bidi

Tags: routes, clojurescript, bidi

I have defined routes in bidi like so in a cljs app:

```
(def routes 
["" {
     "/foo" :bar
    ["/items" :id] :item-do}]
)

(defn- parse-url [url] (bidi/match-route routes url))
(defn- dispatch-route [matched-route]
  (let [panel-name (keyword (name (:handler matched-route)))]
    (dispatch [:active-panel panel-name])))

(def history (pushy/pushy dispatch-route parse-url))
```

When I go to the route "/foo", I get the panel displayed associated with `:bar`, but when I go to the route items/somerandomstring, I expect to see the panel associated with `:item-do`, but instead see a blank page, and in the console it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'                                  myapp.js 1
Reference Error: myapp is not defined.                                      somerandomstring:14
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? How do I correctly match an arbitrary string in a uri in bidi?

-- EDIT --

I've found this:

When I match just this:

```
{
"/foo" index-handler}
```

It works.

But when I match

```
{
"/foo" [:id index-handler]
}
```

Even though `(bidi/match-route routes "/foo/abc")` outputs `{:handler index-handler, :route-params {:id "abc"}}`, 
actually going to this route in the browser gives the error I mentioned.

```
Reference Error: myapp is not defined.                                      somerandomstring:14
```

In the console, somerandomstring:14 is in fact the index.html that I'm sending back, and line 14 is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">myapp.system.go();</script>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax a little wrong:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [bidi.bidi :as bidi] ))

(dotest
  (let [routes ["" {"/foo"    :bar
                    "/items/" {[:id] :item-do}}]]
    (spyx (bidi/match-route routes "/foo" :request-method :get))
    (spyx (bidi/match-route routes "/items/abc" :request-method :get))) )
```

produces the desired output:

```
(bidi/match-route routes "/foo" :request-method :get) 
    => {:handler :bar, 
        :request-method :get}

(bidi/match-route routes "/items/abc" :request-method :get) 
    => {:route-params {:id "abc"}, 
        :handler :item-do,
        :request-method :get}
```

You can see more bidi examples in [this demo project](https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/bidi).

---

### Update #1:

Are you using [figwheel-main](https://figwheel.org/)?  It is much better than the original figwheel.  Be sure to run with `:optimizations :none` as you will get much better error messages.  You may need to update your question with more code and any new/changed error messages.

Also try breaking up the function calls with `println` debugging output, and maybe some unit tests starting from the smallest part and working outward.

---

### Update #2

You are still getting the syntax wrong.  Note that you need to wrap the keyword param in a vector:

```
  (let [foo-handler (fn [& args] "dummy-handler")
        routes      ["" {"/foo/" {[:id] foo-handler}}]
        result      (bidi/match-route routes "/foo/123" :request-method :get)
        handler     (grab :handler result)]
    (is (wild-match? {:route-params   {:id "123"}
                      :handler        :*
                      :request-method :get}
          result))
    (is= "dummy-handler" (handler)))
```

It doesn't matter if the returned value is a keyword like `:foo` or a handler function like `foo-handler`.  `result` still has the same shape:

```
result => {:route-params {:id "123"}, 
           :handler #object[tst.demo.core$fn__20970$foo_handler__21031 0x1926e42e "tst.demo.core$fn__20970$foo_handler__21031@1926e42e"], 
           :request-method :get}
```

Comment: I think I've found the core of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it yet. Check my edit. Also I changed to :optimizations :none, but that didn't change the error  message